# What algebraic curves match the unit circle on the positive quadrant of the plane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, analytic-geometry

Recently, I came across a simple problem whose solution involved showing that a line intersects the unit circle in at most two points. It's easy to find algebraic curves that intersect in the circle in many points (e.g. $4xy=1$ intersects the unit circle at four points).

I am interested to know whether there are algebraic curves that match the unit circle completely in some region, but do not in others. For example:

> Is there an algebraic curve (the zero set of a polynomial in two variables $x$ and $y$) which matches the unit circle (where $x^2+y^2=1$) for all positive values of $x$ and $y$?

The only examples I can find match the unit circle completely for all inputs, and are obtained by multiplying factors in the original equation by $x^2+y^2$. For example, $x^2+y^2(x^2+y^2)=1$ or $x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4=x^2+y^2$.

For other equations, I can find curves which match each other in one region, but differ in another, for example $(x^3+y^3)^2=1$ contains all solutions to $x^3+y^3=1$, as well as distinct points.

Is there an algebraic curve other than the unit circle, which matches the unit circle for all $x,y>0$?

Comment: You can of course get any $n$ points of intersection by Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Hint: Is the union of two (disjoint) circles an algebraic curve?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I do not know. I'm afraid I don't know much about algebraic curves. Is there any simple introductory source you would recommend for me to better understand the problem?

Comment: @Moishe But that won't help the OP get just the first quadrant of the circle :)

Comment: After looking at your question a bit more, I realized that I simply do not understand the expression "matches the unit circle for all $x>0, y>0$." My first reading was "the intersection with the positive quadrant equals $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1, x>0, y>0\}$." But maybe this is not what you have in mind.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Your interpretation is correct, I believe. I'm looking for a polynomial $P$ such that $P(x,y)=0$ whenever $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x>0$, $y>0$. From your first comment, I've realised something like $(x^2+y^2-1)((x-1)^2+y^2-1)=0$ satisfies my original question.

Comment: Would all solutions allow a "factor" of $x^2+y^2-1$ in $P$?

Comment: Right, this would work except it is $(x+1)^2$, not $(x-1)^2$. Yes, all solutions will be **reducible** curves, which amounts to a product of polynomials. All this will be discussed in any algebraic geometry textbooks. I am not sure what is the right reference for your level.....